# Is frequency of K alpha X-ray different for isotopes of the same element?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, electromagnetic-radiation, photons, electrons, atomic-physics

I was thinking that the isotope with more massive nucleus will cause an extra energy gap, due to extra gravitational field, between n=2 and n=1 shells. Even though, the effect will be minuscule, it should cause an increase in energy of photon (and thus frequency) emmited upon transition of electron form n=2 to n=1.

Answer (score 2):

The effect of the gravitational field is about $10^{39}$ times smaller than the electrostatic field miniscule indeed.

It is not the gravitational field that makes the difference but rather the fact that the nucleus does not have an infinite mass and so it has to move to keep the position of the centre of mass of the whole atom constant.

It is easiest to explain for Hydrogen as there is only one electon orbit the nucleus.

The energy levels are given by the equation $E_n = R_{\infty}\frac {1}{n^2}$ where $R_{\infty}$ is the Rydberg constant for a nucleus of infinite mass.

For isotopes of Hydrogen to correct for the finite mass of the nucleus $R_{\infty}$ is reduced by a factor $\dfrac{1}{1+\frac {m_e}{m_N}}$ where $m_e$ is the mass of the electron and $m_N$ is the mass of the nucleus.

These are small corrections as for the lightest isotopes of hydrogen $\frac {m_e}{m_N} = \frac{1}{1836},\;\frac{1}{3670}$ and $\frac{1}{5497}$.
With larger nuclei the effect is even smaller.